# Attempt to Run["inkskape"] fails

Tags: graphics, external-calls

I wrote a little script to convert various graphics files (.ps, .eps, .pdf) to the raster ones (.png). `Export[out, Import[in], ImageSize -> size]` fails for some files without any message at an import step: `Import[in] === $Failed` (well, there’s another issue, something wrong with input files, maybe?). Albeit, Inkscape does the work well via `inkscape $in -w $size -e $out -z`. The problem is: *Mathematica*’s `Run` doesn’t like Inkscape.

```
In[]:= Run["inkscape -z file.ps"]
(*
Emergency save activated!
Emergency save completed. Inkscape will close now.
If you can reproduce this crash, please file a bug at www.inkscape.org
with a detailed description of the steps leading to the crash, so we can fix it.
** Message: Error: Inkscape encountered an internal error and will close now.
*)
Out[]= 139
```

I tried in a notebook, in a shell mode, in a *Mathematica*‌Script. Other GUI programs `Run` properly. A PHP equivalent I had to write

```php
passthru("inkscape $in -w $size -e $out -z")
```

works well, as do bare bash.

What is this hatred between Inkscape and *Mathematica*? Can you reproduce this behaviour? *Mathematica* 9 at Scientific Linux is used.

Comment: Try to use `convert` from ImageMagick or upgrade to version 10 (if your license allows) and try [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DirectControlOfExternalProcesses.html).

Comment: @Szabolcs, I’m going to upgrade as soon as possible. So, in 10 it is solved, isn’t it? (Can’t wait!)
Thanks for proposing ImageMagick, great. But what if I want to deal with vectors?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said it clearly that I did not test this.  I do not have inkscape installed and I do not use Linux.  It is my suspicion that it might work with this new functionality, but I do not know this for certain.  I might be wrong.

Comment: I know for example that when using the front end, `Run["python"]` exits immediately, probably because there's no stdin.  But `StartProcess["python"]` lets `python` keep running until it is explicitly shut down.  I'm on OS X, so similar to Linux.

Comment: @Szabolcs, `Run["python"]` works in terminal. `Run["inkscape"]` or `Run["inkscape -z file"]` does not. `Run["inkscape -z"]` works but only prints ‘Nothing to do!’, not very useful. That’s weird…

Comment: BTW,

`convert -density 1000 tmp/test.eps tmp/test.png
11.27s user 3.17s system 131% cpu 10.998 total`

`inkscape tmp/test.eps -w 1000 -e tmp/test.png -D -z
1.94s user 0.11s system 81% cpu 2.510 total`

Is ImageMagick really so slow or am I doing someting wrong?

Comment: `Run["inkscape -z ~/sample.ps"]` returns `0` for me, so no error. Although it doesn't open anything either.